# How to change text label in symfony 1.4

Tags: php, label, symfony-1.4

In my symfony 1.4 project I want to change label of form text. I can do that by following code:

```
$this->setWidget('first_name', new sfWidgetFormInputText(array('label' => 'First Name')));
```

But I can't do that if I add 'label' in the following code, as probably `sfValidatorString` doesn't accept `'label'`.

```
$this->setValidator('banner_id', new sfValidatorString(array('min_length' => 9)));
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: What does the validator have to do with the label? Widgets (textbox, selectbox, radiobox, etc) have labels, not validators.

Comment: I agree. But using validator I am validating the 'banner_id' field. But I also need to change the label of 'banner_id'. I can do that in my generator.yml file like "banner_id: {label: Employee Id}". But this change affects in other pages too. If I was able to do it like the 'first_name' filed, it would be perfect for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$this->widgetSchema['feildname']->setLabel('Label Text');
```

Comment: this isn't working in my case.If I use it like this         $this->setValidator('banner_id', new sfValidatorString(array('min_length' => 9));        $this->widgetSchema['banner_id']->setLabel('Label Text'); it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can also change all your fields label by using

```
$this->widgetSchema->setLabels(array(
      "widget_name_first" => "my widget label",
      "widget_name_second" => "my widget label",
));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
$this->getWidgetSchema()->setLabel('fieldName', 'Custom label');
```

Or:

```
$this->getWidget('fieldName')->setOption('label', 'Custom label');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also configure your labels from the generator.yml file.
For Example:

```
config:
  actions: ~
  fields:
    date:
      label: Date of birth
      date_format: dd/MM/yy
    address: 
      label: Work address
```